# Store output of find with -print0 in variable

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

I am on macOS and using `find . -type f -not -xattrname "com.apple.FinderInfo" -print0` to create a list of files. I want to store that list and be able to pass it to multiple commands in my script. However, I can't use tee because I need them to be sequential and wait for each to complete. The issue I am having is that since print0 uses the null character if I put it into a variable then I can't use it in commands.

Comment: Which shell are you using? zsh, ancient bash that comes with OS X, modern bash, or posix sh?

Comment: I am using ZSH and on Big Sur

Comment: @Mab2287 : Why are you using `-print0`? I would just put them into an array as: `files=( $(find . -type f -not -xattrname "com.apple.FinderInfo") )`

Comment: I tried that but there are spaces and special characters in the same so it chokes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit verbose, but works with the default bash 3.2:

```sh
eval "$(find ... -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c 'files=( "$@" ); declare -p files' bash)"
```

Now the `files` array should exist in your current shell.

You will want to expand the variable with `"${files[@]}"` including the quotes, to pass the list of files.

Comment: How do I clear out ${files[@]} so that each time this runs it doesn't refuse the data already there?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Is it something to do with some process you don't describe in your question?

Comment: I figured it out. I was using this in a loop and the second iteration still had the original values in `$files` even after this command was ran again. The solution was to put `unset files` above this command to make sure each iteration had a blank slate.

Answer (score 2):

To load 0-delimited data into a shell array (Much better than trying to store multiple filenames in a single string):

`bash` 4.4 or newer:

```sh
readarray -t -d $'\0' files < <(find . -type f -not -xattrname "com.apple.FinderInfo" -print0)

some_command "${files[@]}"
other_command "${files[@]}"
```

Older `bash`, and `zsh`:

```
while read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    files+=("$file")
done < <(find . -type f -not -xattrname "com.apple.FinderInfo" -print0)

some_command "${files[@]}"
other_command "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: If you want to do stuff on one file at a time, instead of passing all the filenames to commands at once, just use a version of the second one that runs those commands inside the loop instead of populating an array.